# Getting row data from database and retrieving it in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, simpleadapter, null-pointer

I am working on a project that has many tables and a table contains multiple rows. How can I get data from database and show it using a `SimpleAdapter`?

I have tried using a cursor but I am only getting the last row value stored in the database.

When trying with `ArrayList<Hashmap<String, String>>` I get a `NullPointerException` and it is not being solved even with a try catch block.

And here is the code for fetching it

```
public class ProducTransection extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    TextView datefrom, dateto;
    Button getbtn;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapname;
    Cursor cl;
    HashMap<String, String> detail = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> detailList;
    ListView lv1;
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ProducTransection.this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.producttransection);

        actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.ptname);
        datefrom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptfromdate);
        dateto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pttodate);
        getbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ptgetbtn);
        lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ptlist);

        Calendar dat = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String formdate = sdf.format(dat.getTime());

        datefrom.setText(formdate);
        dateto.setText(formdate);

        String[] name = db.getName();
        adapname = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProducTransection.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name);
        actv.setAdapter(adapname);

        getbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    detailList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    cl = db.getproducttransection(actv.getText().toString(), datefrom.getText().toString(), dateto.getText().toString());

                    cl.moveToFirst();
                    // do
                    for(int i = 0; i <= cl.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        String date = cl.getString(cl.getColumnIndex("date"));
                        String product = cl.getString(cl.getColumnIndex("product_name"));
                        String price = cl.getString(cl.getColumnIndex("price"));
                        String Qty = cl.getString(cl.getColumnIndex("qty"));

                        detail.put("dat", date);
                        detail.put("pro", product);
                        detail.put("pri", price);
                        detail.put("qty", Qty);
                        detailList.add(detail);

                        SimpleAdapter simadap = new SimpleAdapter(ProducTransection.this, detailList, R.layout.producttransectionui, 
                            new String[] { "dat", "pro", "pri", "qty"}, 
                                new int[]{ R.id.ptuidate, R.id.ptuiproduct, R.id.ptuiprice, R.id.ptuiqty });

                        lv1.setAdapter(simadap);
                    }
                    // while(cl.moveToNext());
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now if I am wrong please help me to getdata and show it in SimpleAdapter.

Comment: post your code and logcat

Comment: This article is very clear to understand how to work with databases: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: @mmlooloo i am not allowed to upload image bcs of not having sufficient points

Comment: @Distwo i have already seen the tutorial but it is not helping

Comment: i do not want you to upload images, i want to post your code. like you type it you can copy and paste your code and use `{}` sign to make it nice also you can save your logcat and paste it;-)

Comment: @mmlooloo here is the code       public Cursor getproducttransection(String Name, String FromDate, String ToDate)
 {
  Cursor result;
  SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
  String product = "SELECT * from everyday_transection"
    +"WHERE date BETWEEN '"+FromDate+"' AND '"+ToDate+"'"
    +"AND name = '"+Name+"'";
  return result = db.rawQuery(product, null);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to recieve your data from sqllite or mysql
 
If its mysql then use php to retrieve data and echo in json format ( google search for that )
And then use **JSON** to parse values in you android app

 and then just display with listview

Comment: sqllite i wrote mysql by mistake

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ORM library since you are working with many tables. This would ease your job of querying and stuff.

To get to know what ORM is, go to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

and to download ORM library for android

http://ormlite.com/

Tutorials on ORM Library,

http://ormlite.com/android/examples/